# Can 't redirect to homepage after login whit <Redirect>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i 'm traying to use Redirect from react-router-dom 4.3.1.
All the logic i apply into mi app.js and i do a get for the token and if exist i have to redirect the user to the homepage..
Also i try to use history, but i dosn 't work.. where is the problem?

app.js

```
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

async componentDidMount() {

  try{
      const urlToken = new URL(window.location) 
      const authToken = urlToken.searchParams.get('auth_token')
      console.log('MATCH ',authToken)

      const tokenUser = await getTokenUser(authToken)
      console.log('tokenUser', tokenUser.status)

       if(tokenUser.status == 200) {
         this.setState({ toHome: true })
       }
     }catch(error){console.log('NOT')}
  }


render(){
if(this.state.toHome == true) {
      return <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of `componentDidMount` is not to return a React element. If you want to redirect the user here, you will have to do it [programmatically](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/).

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, i do it like the example, but trhow me this error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: You should not use <Redirect> outside a <Router>` i edit the question now

Comment: You should use the prop `history` that is passed automatically whenever your inside react-router-dom. i.e. this.props.history.pop() to go back or this.props.history.replace('NameOfComponent') to replace BrowserHistory or push to place another route into the BrowserHistory. 
Because componentDidMount isn't suppose to return anything. If you want to redirect with the <Redirect /> component do it inside of the render()

Comment: Thanks Rafa, but i do the redirect inside the render.. this.props.history shows me an undefined...help!

Comment: Rafa, sorry i was mistake and put the condition outside the return of the render, now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you have to remember is that the Redirect should be part of the returned JSX in your render method.
You have to create a render method in your component. You can return in also conditionally if you want to check something before redirecting. It would look something like:

```
render () {
    return (
        <div>
            {(condition) && <Redirect />}
        </div>)
```